# Rails Showing Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have file importing functionality that imports a file, and logs all errors.

My erroneous solution in the controller it looks something like this. (there is more custom logic to check if error exists.. but omitting for this question)

```
error_report = Item.item_import(params[:file])
redirect_to vendor_path, alert: error_report
```

I am getting a problem when the `error_report` is greater than the allowed 4kb. What is the proper way to show errors and redirect a user? Maybe bind errors to an object and render in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Attach the error to a relevant persisted object. Pull the error from the persistent store on the subsequent page-load.
2. Use a key-value store (e.g. Redis) to persist flash messages instead of cookies (which is where that 4kb limit comes into play).
3. Pre-render an HTML partial with the error messages and cache it in your cache store (something like Memcache) before redirection, then render the cached partial on the next pageload. You could generate a unique key for the partial name, then set it in a separate flash key.
4. Probably not an option in your particular case, but for other situations you could simply truncate the error message to fit within the limits.

Comment: #1 seems like a good option. But how would I attach the error to an object on a redirect? (the redirect goes to another method in the controller)

Comment: @HoosierCoder `Item.logs.create(status: :fail, error: error_report); redirect_to item_path(@item, status: "fail")`. Then on that `show` action: `@error = @item.logs.last.error if params[:status] == "fail"`.

Comment: So, in your approach, you are just setting up a separate "logs" database table. Then recording the error?

Comment: @HoosierCoder I'm using a persistent store (i.e., a SQL database) to keep track of the errors. The example is hypothetical — I don't know what your schema looks like.

Comment: I see, OK yeah that makes sense, to just pull the last error